# Adding rows to a table in android on repeated button click

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, android-gps

Currently I am able to get the current location using GPS in android. I need to add the points(latitude and longitude) to the table as individual rows every time I click the button to get the current location.

This is the xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/table_main"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the java

```
 public void showCurrentLocation() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "First enable LOCATION ACCESS in settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        String message = String.format(

                "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );
        clat = location.getLatitude();
        clon = location.getLongitude();

        String point = String.valueOf(clat) + "," + String.valueOf(clon);
        Double Longitude = (clon);
        Double Latitude = (clat);

        Cod1.setText(String.valueOf((double) Math.round(clat * 1000000d) / 1000000d));
        Cod11.setText(String.valueOf((double) Math.round(clon * 1000000d) / 1000000d));

        cordsList.add(point);

        latitude.add(0.549035);
        Log.e("Latitudes", latitude.toString());

        longitude.add(33.561665);
        Log.e("Longitudes", longitude.toString());


        Log.e("Array", cordsList.toString());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "null location",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    TableLayout stk = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_main);

    TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(this);
    TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
    tv0.setText(" LATITUDE");
    tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tbrow0.addView(tv0);


    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText(" LONGITUDE ");
    tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tbrow0.addView(tv1);


    stk.addView(tbrow0);


        TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);

        TextView t1v = new TextView(this);
        t1v.setText(String.valueOf((double) Math.round(clat * 1000000d) / 1000000d));
        t1v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tbrow.addView(t1v);


        TextView t2v = new TextView(this);
        t2v.setText(String.valueOf((double) Math.round(clon * 1000000d) / 1000000d));
        t2v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tbrow.addView(t2v);



        stk.addView(tbrow);



}
```

The above code can add the rows but keeps repeating the same fields. I would like to insert the row one after the other

Comment: What do you mean by repeating exactly?

Comment: try to add stk.invalidate(); and stk.refreshDrawableState() ; at the end

Comment: I need to get like over ten GPS points. So I need to add every set of points on a button click to the table. Every click should add a row to the table. That is what i mean

Comment: Seems like a `ListView` would be the cleaner solution and certainly more functional.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I am going to use the listview